# Nest Error - ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I have a user auth development on in nest and I have hit another road block

So the user stores fine and has everything needed with bcrypt working great

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop()
  firstname: string;

  @Prop()
  lastname: string;

  @Prop()
  jobtitle: string;

  @Prop()
  startdate: string

  @Prop()
  password: string;

  @Prop()
  username: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

I have a auth service and auth controller

```js
import { Injectable, NotAcceptableException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService, private jwtService: JwtService) { }
    async validateUser(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.usersService.getUser({ username });
        if (!user) return null;
        const passwordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if (!user) {
            throw new NotAcceptableException('could not find the user');
        }
        if (user && passwordValid) {
            return user;
        }
        return null;
    }
    async login(user: any) {
        const payload = { username: user.username, sub: user._id };
        return {
            access_token: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
        };
    }
}
```

```
import { Controller, Request, Post, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    // @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
    @Post('auth/login')
    async login(@Request() req) {
        return this.authService.login(req.user);
    }
}
```

When I go to login function it gives me the error:
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')

For context :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from 'users/interfaces/users.interface';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('Users') private readonly userModel: Model<User>) {}

    //Get all users
    async getUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
        const users = await this.userModel.find().exec();
        return users
    }

    //Get single user
    async getUser(query: object ): Promise<User> {
        return this.userModel.findOne(query);
    }

    async addUser(
        firstname: string, 
        lastname: string, 
        jobtitle: string, 
        startdate: string,
        password: string,
        username: string): Promise<User> {
        return this.userModel.create({
            firstname,
            lastname,
            jobtitle,
            startdate,
            password,
            username
        });
    }

}
```

and the local Strategy

```js
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    super();
  }

  async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username, password);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: `req.user` is `undefined`. I guess it's because you commented-out that `@UseGuards()`

Comment: Also, in your `validateUser` you have the line `if (!user) return null`. Later you have the same check but you throw an exception. Choose one and stick with it, probably the exception throwing. You'll save yourself from a headache later